# Approximation Theory for Deep Learning Models: Where to Start?

Tags: machine-learning, approximation-theory, parameter-estimation

I am working as a novice-developer for company with Deep-learning(DL) Frameworks.

DL is basically consists of several layers of combination of linear and non-linear(usually using ReLU) with millions of yet-determined parameters - then compute the error at the end then re-adjust parameters with given data sets. We call how many layers in which connection - Nerual Net's Architecture, or just simply **Architecture**.

DL is powerful if I use well-known architecture for well-known task. However, if I face another problem to solve, then I have to contrive new architecture considering computational efficiency and how much complexity this architecture can represent- we just call it representation power.

There are very few journals or articles about which level of complexity we can represent for given architecture of neural net.

I can barely search a few of them, such as [Neural networks and rational functions,  M. Telgarsky (2017)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03301.pdf)

If someone ask me what DL is, I always answer simply "function approximation". However, I don't know much about function approximation, even very simple general formulae such as Chebyshev polynomial.

What I'd like to expect with this post is the following:

> 1) Hope to get some more information/references to answer the question 
>   "Which structure of neural architecture is required to solve the given task/problem?"
>
> 1-1) To answer this question, we might need to formulate how to define representation power of the model, and which layer can achieve it.
>
> 2) Any good reference to study Approximation Theories in terms of Neural Net/DL

I hope this post not be too much under-valued because ML/DL frameworks are developed in engineering sector and primarily based on trial and error research culture, but I expect to motivate more theoretical upgrade of this field by active-participation of well-knowleged mathematicians.

Comment: Specifically w.r.t. approximation theory of deep ReLU nets, the (relatively) recent papers of [Liang & Srikant](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.04161), and of [Yarotsky](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01145) are good starting points. Essentially, they both provide constructions of NN approximation schemes to represent reasonably smooth functions on the $d$-dimensional unit cube. Yarotsky also provides decent lower bounds on the number of parameters required for approximation. You can look at papers citing either of these for the recent developements along these lines.

Comment: ^Oh, and once you've read Yarotsky, much of what Telgrasky is doing in the paper you linked will make more sense, particularly his constructions of rational functions from ReLUs. Telgarsky's other paper on the [benefits of depth in NNs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04485) also has a approximation theory flavour, and might be of interest.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 actually, the real problem is, I am keep arguing and having a constructive discussion with my colleague engineers about - "Is this approach really matters?" What I mean, yesterday google also has released their article about searching the more efficient network using Reinforcement learning with 800 GPUs and running it for 28days. This is quite insane in the point of computation. However, in our mathematical approach we only think upon very simply abridged assumed cases - like convex, or continuous..

Comment: Those functions are not found in the nature, or actually not practical in engineering level. Actual function are way more complicated. And Google and other big IT monsters does not borrow the human hand but want to build the fittest neural network by computing itself, not by mathematical indulgence.

Comment: Is it relevant to your day to day ML needs right now? Of course not. 
Is it relevant to the world at large eventually figuring out how DNNs work? Of course yes, theoretical understanding is built on understanding simple cases, what you call 'mathematical indulgence' I call developing abstractions and techniques, some of which may well be key to eventual understanding. Is it relevant to the world at large, in the short term? We increasingly use these systems that we fundamentally do not understand. What that also means is that we do

Comment: (contd.) not understand how they fail. Which means they're intrinsically dangerous to use, and anything that furthers our understanding of them is important. (This is true of so much of ML - we don't even know how to track error through the EM algorithm!) Is it relevant to the world at large, in the long term? Who knows? But every bit of technology that we have exists due to a combination of empirical and theoretical work, much of which had no short term use. And this is far more directed a research.

Comment: Point being that if you want something that today will let you build a better NN, you should be looking at the empirical work going on. Theoretical research is just that - theoretical. It tends to slowly grow and gain relevance, but nothing suggests that it will answer either the scientfic or the technological questions about this stuff in the next $n$ years. But, AFAIK, there's no other way that we're going to get it. And wouldn't you agree that it'll be nice if some day everyone could train good NNs, and not just Google?
(Woah this got too long for a comment chain. Sorry.)

Comment: Did you check this out? https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.02220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to (partly) answer your questions.

> 1) Hope to get some more information/references to answer the question
>   "Which structure of neural architecture is required to solve the given
>   task/problem?"

This is a question that is hard to answer and depends highly on the given task/problem. Currently it is more a trial and error thing then an exact science to say which method/structure/architecture for a neural network works best for which application. The better papers not only implement a (possibly new) method, but also reflect on why these methods seem to be doing better than others. Furthermore, this is not the only thing that impacts the results. It is a combination of network architecture, hyperparamter tuning, loss function choice, data quality, split size of train,test and validation sets and much more. Therefore it is hard to attribute the performance only to the network architecture choice.

But in general: convolutional networks seem to be doing really well for image recognition. Recurrent neural networks also achieve great performance.

> 1-1. To answer this question, we might need to formulate how to
>   define representation power of the model, and which layer can achieve
>   it.

This is even more complicated then what I just described, so I will not go into detail here and refer to the previous question.

> 2) Any good reference to study Approximation Theories in terms of
>   Neural Net/DL

There are some well known results for softmax activation functions. There are also some theoretical results for ReLU architectures. See [here](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2017/098/).